# ¿Cómo puedo validar que consulta me regresa al menos 1 fila?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

Tengo un Data Table que se carga con AJAX tirando una consulta por PDO a la DB, funciona de manera correcta o bueno al menos de la manera que requiero, sin embargo necesito que mediante un SWEET ALERT le indique si se encontró algo en la base de datos o de plano no hay nada coincidente con la solicitud del usuario por medio de "búsqueda por nombre", anexo una previsualización del diseño

[image: Esta es la parte de donde se muestra la carga de los registros desde la base de datos]

Como menciono, si funciona pero no indica si la busque fue exitosa con mínimo algún registro o de plano nada, les dejo código de la consulta a la base de datos de listar_cliente.php

```
<?php
// Requires
require("../database/database.php");
$nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
if(!empty($nombre_cliente)){
    try{
        $conexionWorkspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
        $sentencia = $conexionWorkspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM subcreditos WHERE NOMBRE LIKE ?");
        $sentencia -> bindValue(1, "%$nombre_cliente%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia -> execute();
        $registros_clientes["data"] = [];
        while($clientes = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $registros_clientes["data"][] = $clientes;
        }
        echo json_encode($registros_clientes);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar los comentarios, error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Me imagino que dentro del WHILE debo poner alguna bandera para que AJAX en el response lo notifique como existente y muestre el SWEET ALERT, bien ahora les dejo la parte del frontend para que vean como se carga la DATA TABLE

```
/**
 * Funcion para listar clientes por busqueda de nombre
 * @param  {string} nombre_cliente nombre de cliente para listar clientes en busqueda por nombre
 */
//TODO Notificiacion de cliente no encontrado
function buscarCliente(nombre_cliente){
    if(nombre_cliente.length > 3){
        $("#tabla_busqueda_nombre").DataTable({
            ajax:{
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"../models/listar_cliente.php",
                "data":{nombre_cliente}
            },
            columns:[
                {"data":"SUBCREDITO"},
                {"data":"PRODUCTO"},
                {"data":"NOMBRE"},
                {"data":"FECHA_ASIG"},
                {"data":"AGENTE_ASIG"},
                {sortable: false,
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                        return '<button type="button" id="boton_consulta_nombre_dt" class="boton-consulta-nombre-dt btn btn-primary btn-sm bg-gradient"><i class="bi bi-search text-white"></i></button>';
                    }},
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    "targets": '_all',
                    "className": "text-center fs-13",
                }
            ],
            destroy:true,
            language:{
                "decimal": "",
                "emptyTable": "Realiza una consulta por nombre para cargar registros",
                "info": "Mostrando de _START_ a _END_ comentarios de _TOTAL_ registrados",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 de comentarios registrados",
                "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "thousands": ",",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ comentarios",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando comentarios...",
                "processing": "Procesando comentarios...",
                "search": "Buscar comentario por",
                "zeroRecords": "Sin comentarios encontradas",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Ultimo",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'bottom-start',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 5000,
            didOpen: (toast) => {
                toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
            }
        })
        Toast.fire({
            icon: 'info',
            title: 'Escribre el nombre del cliente a búscar, recuerda escribir al menos 4 letras'
        })
    }
}
```

Como les comento solo me falta la parte que notifica una búsqueda exitosa pero no se como hacer esa parte, espero me haya explicado y me puedan ayudar, igual si tienen algún consejo, lo espero con mucho gusto

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta de DataTable vacía tendría más o menos esta estructura (para más detalles sobre todo esto [revisa la documentación](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side)):

```
{
    "sEcho": 0,
    "iTotalRecords": "0",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "0",
    "aaData": []
}
```

Entonces, tú puedes mandar un objeto con esa estructura cuando verifiques que no hay datos en la consulta. Para simplificar, lo  obtendremos desde una función, por si te interesa mandarlo también desde el `catch`, o desde el `else` inicial, el cual tampoco queda cubierto en tu código.

La función sería esta:

```
function getNoData() {
    $noData='{"sEcho": 0,"iTotalRecords": "0","iTotalDisplayRecords": "0","aaData": []}';
    return json_encode($noData);
}
```

Y para incorporarla a tu código:

```
<?php
// Requires
require("../database/database.php");
$nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
if(!empty($nombre_cliente)){
    try{
        $conexionWorkspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
        $sentencia = $conexionWorkspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM subcreditos WHERE NOMBRE LIKE ?");
        $sentencia -> bindValue(1, "%$nombre_cliente%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia -> execute();
        $registros_clientes["data"] = [];
        while($clientes = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $registros_clientes["data"][] = $clientes;
        }
        # Cuando no haya filas
        # $registros_clientes["data"] estará vacío
        # así que lo podemos usar aquí para verificar
        if($registros_clientes["data"]) {
            echo json_encode($registros_clientes);;
        }else{
            echo getNoData();
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar los comentarios, error: " . $e->getMessage();
        # Si quieres mandar un noData también si
        # se captura una Exception, puedes cambiar el echo
        # de más arriba por esto
        echo getNoData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sí mal no entendí A. Cedano aquí con tu aporte, notifica en el date table un "0 registros" ó "registros no encontrados" pero si necesito algo así como un "alert" de Bootstrap que notifique con eso "registro no encontrado"

Comment: @Minor pues en ese caso tendrías que verificar la respuesta en Javascript y si `aaData` está vacío, emitir la alerta que requieres, eso es algo que corresponde a la lógica que maneja la respuesta en el cliente, es decir, en Javascript.